# Get elements center x & y position based on provided screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it is possible to get the center position of an element at a specific provided screen size using jQuery?

What I want to achieve is the ability to get the center position of an element based on an input of a height and width.

For example if I provided the screen size (1440px, 980px) could I pass those values to a function and calculate where an html element's center x & y position would be?

I have the following code calculating the x & y center position of an element at the current screen size on the pages load, but I want the ability to pass a screen size in a function and calculate the elements center coordinate points from there. (I don't want to use the resize() function. I want the ability to calculate the coordinates without resizing the screen.)

```
<script>
var $this = $("#element");
var offset = $this.offset();
var width = $this.width();
var height = $this.height();

var window_height = $(window).height();
var window_width = $(window).width();

var centerX = offset.left + width / 2;
var centerY = offset.top + height / 2;

console.log(Math.round(centerX));
console.log(Math.round(centerY));
</script>
```

EDIT: Let me try and provide a little more background on what I am trying to do. I am using [heatmap.js](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) to show a heatmap over a website screenshot. The screen shot has a specific size of 1440px by 980px (or something along those lines.) I want to be able to calculate the coordinates where I can overlay the heatmap over the screenshot over specific html elements to show a click count, but the screenshot size is different then the underlying webpage size which effects the x & y coordinates and how the heatmap is displayed. That's the reason I want to be able to get the coordinates based on a specific screen size.

```
var points = [{x: 341, y: 881, value: 90}, {x: 720, y: 884, value: 10}, {x: 1100, y: 881, value: 20}, {x: 340, y: 1138, value: 1}, {x: 720, y: 1136, value: 15}, {x: 1100, y: 1140, value: 12}];
```

Comment: How is an element's center position dependent on the screen size exactly? Noticed how yourself don't use `window_height` & `window_width`?

Comment: Centering can be achieved via `getBoundingClientRect`, iewithout querying the window dimensions

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla alternative based on @Dacre anwser

```
const eye = document.querySelector('.eye')
const { left, top, width, height } = eye.getBoundingClientRect()
const centerX = left + width / 2
const centerY = top + height / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked really well for me:

```
x: element.getBoundingClientRect().left + document.documentElement.scrollLeft + element.clientWidth / 2,
y: element.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop + element.clientHeight / 2,
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use `.getBoundingClientRect()` to achieve this. According to MDN:

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

Try the following:

```
<script>
var $this = $("#element");
// [UPDATE] Use native getBoundingClientRect method
var offset = ($this[0]).getBoundingClientRect(); 
var width = $this.width();
var height = $this.height();

var window_height = $(window).height();
var window_width = $(window).width();

var centerX = offset.left + width / 2;
var centerY = offset.top + height / 2;

console.log(Math.round(centerX));
console.log(Math.round(centerY));
</script>
```

Comment: this is wrong. left - width is not center. shoudl be left +width/2